# DD4T 2 Java and Maven Build Failing

Tags: dd4t, web8, java, maven

I'm trying to Build DD4T 2 Java, using the following POM's and Maven (with version changed from 2.0.6-SNAPSHOT to 2.0.5. I am using the 'cd-8.1.0' profile for the CIL / CIS dependencies

- **POM** - https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/dd4t-test-spring-web/pom.xml
- **Parent POM** - https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/pom.xml

90% of the build is fine, but I get the following errors stopping the successful build.

> [WARNING] The POM for com.tridion:cd_ambient:jar:8.1.0 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>
> [WARNING] The POM for com.tridion:cd_cache:jar:8.1.0 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>
> [WARNING] The POM for com.tridion:cd_core:jar:8.1.0 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>
> [WARNING] The POM for com.tridion:cd_model:jar:8.1.0 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>
> [WARNING] The POM for com.vs.ezlicrun:easylicense:jar:2.5 is missing,
>   no dependency information available

Comment: the fact that your dependencies include `easylicense:jar` sounds like you are using the in process profile, and not the CIL one. Also rather than using the 8.1.0 versions (which is Web 8 GA), you should be using the 8.1.1 (Web 8 CU1) versions now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These dependencies aren't available from maven central. You need to host those yourself. To find out which items are hosted on Maven central:

Check http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.tridion%22

So they can't be resolved without hosting them yourself.

Use Artifactory or Sonatype Nexus to make this happen.
The instructions for hosting the items yourself are on Github: https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/wiki/Dependency-Management

**Update:** There are newer versions of these items available on maven central (Except the easlicense jar) you could also try to get things working with those dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Maven look for dependencies in your **local repository** first, if not found there then in **Maven Central**.

All those missing dependencies are neither available in your local repository nor in Maven Central Repository. 
I came across the same problem and what i did is following:

1. Copied all the jars from my SDL Web8 setup folder[Most of them are present in "Content Delivery"] some of them were not there i searched them in **maven central** too, like.
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tridion/cd_model/8.1.1-1005
2. Once i got all the jars, i placed them in one folder and renamed them as expected by my pom(like in your case it should look like cd_ambient-8.1.0)
3. After getting all of them renamed, made a batch file "**maven-install.bat**" which contained following maven commands[You can run them one by one too.]

> ```
>     REM see DD4T dependency naming on https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/README.md
>
>     @echo off
>     rem Install Tridion Content Delivery libraries and necessary third-party libraries in the local Maven repository
>
>     echo Installing Tridion Content Delivery libraries into the local Maven repository...
>     call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tridion -DartifactId=cd_ambient         -Dversion=8.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=cd_ambient-8.1.0.jar
>     call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tridion -DartifactId=cd_cache           -Dversion=8.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=cd_cache-8.1.0.jar
>     call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tridion -DartifactId=cd_core            -Dversion=8.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=cd_core-8.1.0.jar
>     call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tridion -DartifactId=cd_model           -Dversion=8.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=cd_model-8.1.0.jar
>
>     echo Installing third-party libraries into the local Maven repository...
>     call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.vs.ezlicrun -DartifactId=easylicense -Dversion=2.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=easylicense-2.5.jar
>
>     echo Finished
>     pause
> ```

Moved this **maven-install.bat** file in the same folder where i placed all my jars. And by running this file, all my mentioned jars got installed in my **local maven repository**.

Build you project and these jars will be referenced and will become part of your project's Maven Dependencies.